# Timeglider object always staying empty and undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, plugins

So my example is really basic. Actually not even the basic example from the Timeglider examples is working:

```
var tg1 = {};
    $(function () { 
        tg1 = $("#placement").timeline({
                "icon_folder":"timeglider/icons/",
                "data_source":"json/idaho.json"
        });
        tg_actor = tg1.data("timeline");
        tg_actor.zoom(1);
    });
```

It says that `tg1.data("timeline")`is undefined. Even though there is data in there.

So my issue is that I cannot create an instance of the Timeglider plugin. So I'm not able to use it's functions. Could someone tell me why the data object is always undefined?

### Here it is working...

So I found this running example: http://www.avo.alaska.edu/includes/js/timeglider/kitchen_sink.html and here it is working properly. I studied the code and it's nearly the same I have. So what could I have done different?

### Working with older jQuery version

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js is working without an error. How can I use the latest jQuery? Even with the migrate plugin I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with 1.11.2 of jQuery (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js) so it seems like this plugin is just no compatible to the latest version.

Comment: Any idea what functions might need to be changed to get it to work with the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: As someone told me that the last 1.* is the same like the 2.* I have no idea what could be reason. I already written to the author of TimeGlider and got an answer and told him about that issue. But until now no solution, so this is really something on TimeGlider side I believe that is hardcoded.

Comment: I suspect they're using deprecated functions that are no longer supported in later versions of jQuery. Really should be looked at by the author at some point, it's an awesome widget and I'd hate to see it go to waste. +1 for figuring out the issue was the jQuery version... saved me some trouble.

Comment: Yeah actually I also use it in my current project and works without issues except this one. But if the developer does not mention the issue somewhere it's hard for the community to fix it. And yeah actually it took me a few days to try an older version of jQuery. But sometimes you need to test anything ;)